# Why do thse two methods yield the same estimate [with code]?

Tags: r, regression, fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference

When, if ever, do OLS applied to the first differences yield the same estimates as the difference-in-differences method?

I am running the following (in R):

```
set.seed(42)
# Make som data:
treatment  <- round(runif(10, 0, 1), 0)
pnr        <- round(runif(10, 100, 1000),0)
health     <- round(runif(10, 0, 10), 0) 
health2    <- round(runif(10, 0, 10), 0) 
data1              <- data.frame(pnr, treatment, health, 2006)
data2              <- data.frame(pnr, treatment, health2, 2008)
colnames(data1)[4] <- "year"
colnames(data2)    <- c("pnr", "treatment", "health", "year")

#Bind it togehter:
require(plyr)
data      <- rbind.fill(data1, data2)

#DiD dummies:
data$d2   <- ifelse(data$year == 2008, 1, 0)
data$txd2 <- data$treat * data$d2

#Do regressions:
reg1 <- lm(health ~ treatment + d2 + txd2, data = data)

require(plm)
fd1  <- plm(health ~ treatment + d2 + txd2, data = data, index = c("pnr", "year"),
        model = "fd")
```

The estimate of txd2 the "difference in difference" estimate, yields 7 in both cases. No matter how I generate the data, the estimates are always equal. This should not be case, but I cannot figure out where I mess it up.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with R code but it seems you generated the outcome as a random variable. Usually you would simulate the outcome by directly modelling the data generating process where you also set the value of the coefficients, e.g. $y_{it} = 0.8 + \epsilon$, $\epsilon \sim N(0,1)$ for control units and treated units in the pre-treatment period, and $y_{it} = 0.8 + 1.2(treatment) + \epsilon$ for treated units in the post-treatment period. So the "true" coefficient of the treatment would be 1.2

Comment: I actually figured it out in the mean time. 
They should yield the same estimate in the simple 2 period model, without other observables.

Comment: Okay, great. Would you be so kind and post your finding as answer and accept it? This way future readers will know how this problem was solved.

Comment: Please explain what you're actually doing (without code) first, then if you wish, have the code at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Well the simple answer turned out to be: they should yield the same estimate. 
In the simple two period model, with no addtional controls, FD and DID yield the same estimate. That are at least two ways to see this. Either write up the DiD model and first difference it. Or write up the DiD estimator, and reorganize into the FD estimator.

This is what the regressions showed, which was what tricked me in the first place.